# Can't connect to remote DB via PDO on PHP7 server

Tags: mysql, pdo

I try to connect to remote DB via PDO with such code

`$dsn = 'mysql:host=DB_HOST;port=DB_PORT;dbname=DB_NAME';
 $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user,$password);`

And on PHP7 (7.0.22) machine I got such error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` but on PHP5(5.5.22) machine I didn't get any error and all works pretty good. And that the most annoying thing.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for inaccuracy this is not 2 servers this is one server with different versions of PHP (before was PHP5 now is PHP7 after updating)

**UPDATE**

for @Your Common Sense 
as I mentioned before it works if I use PHP 5.5.22 version and it doesn't if I use PHP 7.0.22 on the same server. So I wonder if it's issue with PHP or MySQL

Any suggestion (except "Try to ping your remote DB server" .....)?

Comment: Does the server allow connections from both remote PHP servers?

Comment: Do the two machines have the same IP address? Maybe the one with PHP7 doesn't have access because of the firewall or something.

Comment: "Try to ping remote DB server" do you get a timeout when you do?

Comment: I don't know your configuration, but can you try accessing it from MySQL workbench or the like to ensure the account works etc?

Comment: @VTodorov there is no any over timeout than it was before

Comment: @KeithChason Yes I can, account works OK

Comment: Can you English?

Comment: @VTodorov what about my question? not about my English))

Comment: I'm trying to understand your comment "there is no any over timeout than it was before" in order to help you. That's about the question.

Comment: @VTodorov OK, let's do it simpler - no, I don't have timeout

Comment: Verify the IP of the new server.

Comment: Verify the port of the server. PS mariaDB has a default port 3307 and not 3306!

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes? Maybe? No? Source: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, I have used it a couple of times. Both of which it defaulted at 3307 for me.